# When the first element is added to a std::list, is an iterator obtained from begin() invalidated?

Tags: c++, iterator, stdlist

Does the following give defined results in terms of the C++ standard?

```
std::list<int> myList;
std::list<int>::iterator myIter = myList.begin();    // any issues?
myList.push_back( 123 );
myIter++;                                  // will myIter point to the 123 I pushed?
```

I can test this out on the compiler I'm using... but I'd like a more definitive answer.

This is a different question from [this one about empty vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796200/is-begin-end-for-any-empty-vector) because it involves asking about the state of iterators AFTER the container ceases to be empty().

Answer (score 26, accepted):

All standard iterator and container types behave the same in this regard:

`§23.2.1 [container.requirements.general] p6`

> `begin()` returns an iterator referring to the first element in the container. `end()` returns an iterator which is the past-the-end value for the container. **If the container is empty, then `begin() == end()`;**

And table 107 in `§24.2.3 [input.iterators]` demands that as a precondition for `++it`, `it` shall be dereferenceable, which is not the case for past-the-end iterators (i.e., what you get from `end()`), as such you're treading into the dreaded domain of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

```
std::list<int> myList;
std::list<int> myIter = myList.begin();
```

The iterator has the same value as if you were initializing it with `myList.end()`. The iterator is initialized to on-past-the-end position. Even after you push an element into the list the iterator still points one-past-the-end. If you increment it, you are invoking undefined behaviour.

UPDATE:

E.g., if you compile your snippet with GCC with -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG, the resulting executable will abort:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/debug/safe_iterator.h:236:error: attempt to increment 
    a past-the-end iterator.

Objects involved in the operation:
iterator "this" @ 0x0x7fffc9548fb0 {
type = N11__gnu_debug14_Safe_iteratorINSt9__cxx199814_List_iteratorIiEENSt7__debug4listIiSaIiEEEEE (mutable iterator);
  state = past-the-end;
  references sequence with type `NSt7__debug4listIiSaIiEEE' @ 0x0x7fffc9548fb0
}
zsh: abort (core dumped)  ./listiter
```

Comment: ...except that when you have a circular list, one-past-the-end might give you a legitimate beginning point by some definitions. So are you absolutely sure... or making an educated guess?

Comment: @omatai: `std::list<>` is not circular.

Comment: Ah - yes - in my tired mind, I confused "doubly-linked" with "circular" because every time I used to (years ago) make a doubly-linked list, it always had a single head/tail which completed a "circle". D'Oh! I need to go home...

Comment: @wilx: _usually_ it isn't. But it can be, more or less: `++end()` is undefined so it could be `begin()`. However, there are `N+1` distinct iterators if you have `N` values.