# Is begin() == end() for any empty() vector?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdvector

I have long assumed that for any empty `std::vector` *V*, `V.begin() == V.end()`. Yet I see nothing in the C++ specification that states this to *always* be true. Is it necessarily true or does it just happen to be true on most implementations?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked, though I'm having trouble finding it, and I'm pretty sure they're equal.

Comment: if it weren't true it would invalidate all the common patterns for iterating on a vector... ;)

Comment: Related question: if both `begin()` and `end()` are casted to pointers first, does the equality still hold? I'm worried that even the casting is undefined?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Yes, that's what the standard requires it to be for `empty()` for any container.

§ 23.2.1 Table 96 of the C++11 standard says:

```
 +----------+---------------+----------------------+
 |Expression|  Return Type  | Operational Semantics|
 |----------|---------------|----------------------|
 |a.empty() |Convertible    |a.begin() == a.end()  |
 |          |to bool        |                      |
 |          |               |                      |
 +-------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 28):

**23.2.1 General container requirements**, specifically Table 96 **Container Requirements** has

> `a.empty()` convertible to `bool`, operational semantics `a.begin() == a.end()`

Then

> 6 `begin()` returns an iterator referring to the first element in the container. `end()` returns an iterator which
>   is the past-the-end value for the container. **If the container is empty, then `begin() == end();`**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is true. Here is the [proof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin). And, of course, `std::distance(a.begin(), a.end()) == 0` for an empty vector.

Comment: *Proof* would be a Standard citation, not a like to a reference site.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/

If the container is empty, end() is the same as begin().

Comment: More reliable resource, than cplusplus.com: [std::vector::empty](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty).