# c++ empty std::vector begin not equals to end

Tags: c++, vector, windows-10, std

Hi I have situation on windows 10, that declared empty class member variable vector, but this vector's `begin()(first iterator)` and `end()(last iterator)` differ, as I know in empty vector those 2 should be same. Any ideas? :)))

```
struct B  
{  
    std::string a;  

    std::string b;  
};

class A
{  
    A();  

    std::vector<B> vec_;    
};  

A::A()  
{

}
```

Here in costructor A `vec_.begin().base()` not equals `vec_.end().base()`

Which as I know should be equal

Comment: Don't look at the addresses, just compare them. `operator==` should do the right thing. The standard doesn't declare that they'll return the same iterator, only that they'll compare equal.

Comment: what compiler? You're going to have to post a complete code sample that reproduces this

Comment: Show as some code to reproduce

Comment: That code is neither minimal nor complete. I'd like to see the actual code of the comparison which actually fails, not some text describing it.

Comment: base() does not seems to be part of C++ specification anyway (at least not for regular iterators returned from `begin()` and `end()`) - MSVC 2013 (C++11) does not know it. But it seems that GCC provides `base()` as non-portable extension.

Comment: I can't see it in gcc 5.2.0 locally - what does it return?

Comment: Perhaps you've discovered the reason that `base` wasn't defined in the standard for non-reverse iterators.

Comment: But the talk is not about base, talk is that on Windows 10 the begin and end are different, I dont know much about vectors, but are there casesin which they might differ? I cant show the code as its a closed source

Comment: The talk is about base because `base` is not defined to be a member function of a vector iterator in the c++ standard and would be implementation defined at best. So we cannot say why `begin().base()` is not equal to `end().base()` because we do not know what `base` does

Comment: @Irakli Darbuashvili: So far you provided no evidence whatsoever that `begin()` and `end()` are different. Until you do (show the code), there's no "talk" of any kind here at all.

Answer (score 3):

The standard only requires that the iterators are equal, **not** that their adresses are the same. Considering the adresses of iterators is pointless.

As other have stated, the two iterators are different objects, so they **need** to have different adresses.

For reference, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17796230/193789).

Comment: Yes you are right. I was not clear, the iterators are different.

Comment: The bases of begin and end are not equal. vec.begin().base() != vec.end().base(), which should be equal

Comment: @Irakli Darbuashvili: What "bases" are you talking about? In C++ only reverse iterators have "bases". Non-reverse iterators don't. `vec.begin().base()` is not compilable. Your library implementation apparently somehow allows you to call `base()` on non-reverse iterators. That does not mean that you should do it. And that does not mean that the result of the comparison of those bases has any specific meaning.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<int> v;
assert(v.begin() == v.end());
```

This should work: begin and end compare equal.

On the other hand

```
auto b = v.begin();
auto e = v.end();
assert(&b == &e);
```

is *prohibited* from working: the two iterators are different objects and must have different addresses.

Compare the equivalent:

```
int i = 42;
int j = 42;
assert(i == j);   // ok
assert(&i == &j); // fail
```

Comment: Ok you are right, but shouldnt v.begin().base() == v.end().base()?

Comment: Does `std::vector<T>::iterator` even have a `base` method? I was only aware of that for `reverse_iterator`. Now you need to show your _actual_ code and your platform if you want more help, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: I also didnt know but it has such method. Check the stl_iterator header file

Comment: That sounds like a non-standard implementation detail to me - I certainly can't see anything similar in either the standard, my local headers or any online references.

Answer (score 0):

The iterators are returned by value, so the address will indeed not be the same. Even if you do:

```
const vector<whatever>::iterator &it1 = vect.begin();
const vector<whatever>::iterator &it2 = vect.begin();
```

the addresses of `it1` and `it2` can be different (and will be in many implementations) - even if references are used.

(note that using `begin()` in both is not a mistake - the same method `begin()` will return two different objects with different values)

Comment: They are not _often_ returned by value, they are [defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) to be returned by value.

Comment: Yes I know, but I was not clear, the begin and end differ. The itterators are different