# Is it legal to use the insert member function to insert a range into an empty vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Is it legal to `insert` into the `std::vector` named `myvec` when it is empty? Like so:

```
myvec.insert(myvec.end(), other.begin(), other.end());
```

I'm not sure where `myvec.end()` would point in that case.

Also, when `myvec` is empty, is the above different from the following?

```
myvec.insert(myvec.begin(), other.begin(), other.end());
```

Are any of these legal?

Comment: this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796200/is-begin-end-for-any-empty-vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly legal. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert):

> Causes reallocation if the new size() is greater than the old capacity(). If the new size() is greater than capacity(),

---

> when myvec is empty, is the above different from the following?

No, because when a vector is empty, `vector::begin() == vector::end()`. So they are both same.

Comment: Thanks. So are both of the above variations legal?

Comment: IMO the quote has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Yes, both are legal because for empty vector `begin() == end()`

Comment: @bartop It *is* relevant, no? Because even though `begin() == end()` for an empty vector - if there's no memory allocated yet, where is the data to be stored?

Comment: @AvivCohn: Same as in any other case where you add to `std::vector` beyond what it can hold -- it (re)allocates more memory.

Comment: @DevSolar I see what you mean. Anyway somehow it did help the answer click for me. There was an inconvenience in my mind with inserting before an iterator the points to the beginning of a buffer that hasn't been allocated yet. That quote eased my mind :)

Comment: @AvivCohn: Consider `std::string s; s = "Hello";`. That string doesn't have memory allocated before either. (Actually, it probably doesn't have so afterwards because of small strings optimization, but you get the idea.)

Comment: @AvivCohn: In addition to the previous comments, note also that an empty vector can have a non-zero `capacity`. Empty just means that it contains no objects, `size==0`. But all you know is that `capacity>=size`.

Answer (score 3):

[C++20 final working draft](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) 22.2.1 General container requirements [container.requirements.general]

> 6. begin() returns an iterator referring to the first element in the
>    container. end() returns an iterator which is the past-the-end value
>    for the container. If the container is empty, then begin() == end().

Yes they are the same. Are they legal?

From cppreference on `std::vector` [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

```
template< class InputIt >
void insert( iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last);
```

Is iterator pos valid? (i.e. std::begin of an empty vector). [Yes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/) it is, but you shall not dereference it.

Comment: Welcome to the 10k club :)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica feels good :)

Answer (score 1):

By definition a container is `empty` when `begin() == end()`. See [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17796230/4117728). In other words, `end()` and  `begin()` can be used on an empty container (though you cannot dereference them). Consequently, an empty vector does not constitute a special case when calling algorithms. If

```
myvec.insert(myvec.end(), other.begin(), other.end());
```

is fine with `myvec` that has elements, then it is also fine for an empty `myvec` (also whether `other` has elements or not does not require extra handling on that call).